# Restore Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, system-restore

Earlier today, I tried to restore my Windows Server 2008 R2 server from a Windows Server backup file.  The process it followed (which I had used in the past on Server 2003) was

1. Do quick load of OS from CD
2. Restore backup from external drive.

When I went to restore, I didn't see an option to restore entire system.  I had to choose volumes, applications, system state etc.  I chose system state and the restore completed; however the server bluescreened when it came back up.

My question is, when doing a restore in the way that I described above, do I need to first restore the C drive, then restore the system state?

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you simply asking HOW to restore a 2008 server using the built in Windows backup?  Technet covers that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494ff831-ddb7-4c50-aa3d-19c8deb84efb

Comment: Yes I am since the way I originally tried failed.  I was able to restore the server using another method; i.e. Boot from CD and do a repair.  Just not sure which is the best method.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Per your comment, I'm making this my answer.  There isn't a "best" way...so much as there is a preferred method depending on what you are wanting to recover and the scope of the recovery.

Because it appears you are using the built in Windows Backup utility:

You can learn about the various methods to restore your 2008 server here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/494ff831-ddb7-4c50-aa3d-19c8deb84efb

Specifically, if you are wanting a full system restore, you can find that info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755163

Bear in mind that when dealing with a domain controller, it is different and you'll need to read the first link and subsequent links about AD/DC restores to fully grasp their implications.

Comment: Thank you so much for the posts.  I really appreciate it.